# Dynamodb read from Android studio

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-dynamodb

I am creating a quiz game app where it will pull up questions from dynamodb database tables. Wondering how can I achieve this . I just need to read from dynamodb through Android. Also, for pushing questions I want to do with different admin account. I implemented using AWS amplify but it more likely creates persistent db but not sure how to pull from dynamodb. Any help/guidance deeply appreciated. Checked AWS help but could not find something helpful.

Tried AWS amplify .. it created persistent db but not sure how to pull questions from dynamo with no sync as such. Just pull from db

Comment: Any help/direction deeply appreciated ...

Comment: Does anyone have any clue on this .. any direction appreciated